# Huawei 303 3g dongle not recognized as modem Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: 10.04, usb-modem

output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 12d1:1506 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
```

last few lines of `lsusb -vd 12d1:1506`:

```
Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x07  EP 7 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               1
can't get device qualifier: Operation not permitted
can't get debug descriptor: Operation not permitted
cannot read device status, Operation not permitted (1)
```

output of `usb-devices`:

```
T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  5 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=12d1 ProdID=1506 Rev=01.02
S:  Manufacturer=HUAWEI
S:  Product=HUAWEI Mobile
C:  #Ifs= 6 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=03 Prot=01 Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=03 Prot=16 Driver=option
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=03 Prot=03 Driver=option
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=03 Prot=02 Driver=option
I:  If#= 4 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
I:  If#= 5 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
```

last few lines of `dmesg | grep -i usb`:

```
[ 3991.284770] usb 2-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 3991.285411] usb 2-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[ 3991.285747] usb 2-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[ 3991.286076] usb 2-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB3
[ 3992.745243] usb-storage: device scan complete
[ 3992.745250] usb-storage: device scan complete
[15831.942156] option1 ttyUSB0: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
```

I've installed "usb_modeswitch" version 1.1.0

content of the "/etc/usb_modeswitch.d/12d1:1506" file is

```
enter code here
```

DefaultVendor= 0x12d1
DefaultProduct=0x1506

TargetVendor= 0x12d1
TargetProduct=0x1506
MessageContent="55534243f066fe892400000080000612000000240000000000000000000000"

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [usb_modeswitch](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/usb-modeswitch) [image: Install usb_modeswitch] to switch the device from storage to modem mode. It should recognise your device as soon as you plug it in the next time with the current version (which isn't the one in the Ubuntu repositories, but it may still work). If not, I'll translate http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/USB_ModeSwitch#Huawei-Sticks, since I didn't find an English version of this.

Comment: This is the content of the file "/etc/usb_modeswitch.d12d1:1506" file  <br/> `********** DefaultVendor= 0x12d1 DefaultProduct=0x1506 TargetVendor= 0x12d1 TargetProduct=0x1506 MessageContent="55534243f066fe892400000080000612000000240000000000000000000000`

Comment: Acknowledged. What's your point? If you want to provide further information about the problem it would be best, if you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/537797/edit) your question to include that info.

Comment: My point was that I installed "usb_modeswitch". But this still did not work.

Comment: Ok, can you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/537797/edit) your question to contain a note that you installed `usb_modeswitch`, its version, and the contents of that file? That would be a better place because of readability.